# Internal Server Error with status code 500 in SOAP request

Tags: xml, oracle, web-services, soap, plsql

I have been facing some issue while calling a web service request through SOAP message format.

```
<faultcode>ns0:Client</faultcode><faultstring>Cannot find dispatch method for 
     {http://pmts.ofss.com/ws/PMSIMaintenanceService}CREATESIMAINTENANCE_FSFS_REQ</faultstring>
```

Comment: below is the SOAP XML request

Comment: Sounds like you should be raising this with whoever owns the web service you are calling.

Comment: Due to the minimal information you have provided, we won't be able to help you most likely. Though it seems to be a service issue however, unless you are missing something whilst calling it, which causes it to display that error.